# Looking for a Hermione Granger and Draco Malfoy love story

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, dramione

I read a Hermione and Draco love story a few years ago on [QuoteV](https://www.quotev.com/fanfic) but I think it has been deleted since. It was about Draco being forced to stay with Hermione during a probation period forcing him to be under surveillance and with no magic until he was deemed reformed I think. Hermione lived at home with her parents after being cheated on by Ron Weasley. They slowly grow to like each other and then to love but Ron attacks Draco causing him to be injured. Also Draco cannot say he loves Hermione due to a curse his father put on him.

Hermione, I think, gets kidnapped by Lucius Malfoy and Draco saves her and they have a happily ever after. It is a good fan fiction. I just cannot find it anywhere and was wondering if someone else knows of a secondary site it’s on? Or if it is still on QuoteV but under a different name?

Comment: That's a pretty well-written story ID question; why the downvotes?

Comment: @desertnaut there seems to be a group of people on the site who down vote any Harry Potter fan fiction story id question regardless of its quality.

Comment: May be this one? https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9333957/1/One-Year-One-Life

Comment: I have to say I dissagree with you when you say this is a good fan fiction.